# Press any key to boot doesn't respond

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to boot from a CD. I changed the boot priority to my DVD/CD reader. The boot menu says "Press any key to boot". I tried every key but it won't respond and it just boots up Windows 7 normally. (I'm trying to reinstall Windows 7.)
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What brand/model of computer? Will it boot to any other disks? Does your Windows 7 disk boot on a different PC?

Comment: Have you tried using a different keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

In 2014 it is unlikely that your PC is old enough to rely on PS/2 connection for the keyboard to work, so I assume your keyboard is a native laptop one or is connected via USB.

If you use a laptop, try to get into the BIOS interface, then disable the second boot device (it looks like your first boot device is already the DVD drive, and the second one is the hard disk).

If you are using a USB keyboard, don't connect it through a hub, connect it directly to a slot at your PC, and don't use a USB3 slot. Try different ones until it works.

If you use a wireless keyboard, switch to a USB one for this. Drivers for the wireless connection will not be loaded at this point, same probably for USB3.